# How do I login Via a Button using VB and a Web Browser Element

Tags: vb.net

I've added a web browser element to my form and have been able to enter information into the box.  When entering the correct information the webpage tries to download, how do I stop this from happening?

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim usernameTextBox As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("Email")
    usernameTextBox.InnerText = "******"

    Dim passwordTextBox As HtmlElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("Password")
    passwordTextBox.InnerText = "******"
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("https://squareup.com/terminal/"))
End Sub
End Class
```

The output tries to download the webpage     [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFII5.png)

Comment: Can you post the HTML? You really have a few options.  Use a JS preventDefault() for OnClientClick, or set the DefaultButton attribute on the <div> or <panel> surrounding the textboxes/button

Comment: I haven't used any HTML just the website ""https://squareup.com/terminal/"" which i used when referring to the textbox

Comment: And when you hit the "Enter" button the keyboard it tries to download, or when you actually mouse click too it tries to download?

Comment: Yes, either way I select the button the website tried to download

Comment: Would have thought there was at least some HTML, at least for the control.  But here is some documentation that might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for this however I am still not understanding why the web-browser is trying to download.

Comment: It's hard to say with only the code your provided.  Your button click is obviously not redirecting or trying to download. There might be some JS or other client-side code that is running on the button click.  When you debug, are you actually getting in the Button1_Click function?

Comment: So theirs nothing i can do?

Comment: So there is no other code involved in this page or rendering out the WebBroswer?